# Will another thread execute while another thread waits for an HTTP response?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-requests, sleep

So I just finished watching [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=olYdb0DdGtM) video on youtube. To my understanding while one thread sleeps, other threads in a program can run. My question is, is waiting for a HTTP response considered "sleeping" ? And will other tasks execute while waiting for a response?

For example:

```
from threading import Thread
from requests import get

def send_request():
    response = get('https://www.google.com/')
    return response

def add(x):
    return x + 2

t1 = Thread(target=send_request)
# t1.start()
t2 = Thread(target=add, args=(1,))
# t2.start()
t3 = Thread(target=add, args=(3,))
# t3.start()

t1.start()
t2.start()
t3.start()
```

Let's say it takes 100 milliseconds to get a response from `get('https://www.google.com/')` will `t1` and `t2` execute within the 100 milliseconds to get a response? What difference does it make when I call `.start()` on each thread object after **ALL** are instantiated oppose to calling `.start()` after **EACH** instantiation?

Thanks for all of those who reply in advance!

Comment: Other threads will run during waiting for response. It doesn't matter much when "start" is called. The precise order and time when and how long each thread is executed is not predictable anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Is waiting for a HTTP response considered "sleeping"?

Waiting for the HTTP response is slow, and the CPU will most likely switch to run the other threads before the response is available. So the answer is **yes**.

#### Will other tasks execute while waiting for a response?

**Yes**. If you place a `print` statement inside the `add` and `send_request` functions, you'll see that the `add` will print its output before `send_request`.

#### What difference does it make when I call `.start()` on each thread object after ALL are instantiated oppose to calling `.start()` after EACH instantiation?

There is practically **no difference**. When a thread is started (using `start()`), it is set to run concurrently with the main program's thread. The main thread can start other threads too, and they will run concurrently as well.